# How should I link redmine roadmap versions with git tags?

Tags: git, redmine

I am trying to establish a logical link between redmine project versions and git tags.

Currently my solution involves creating a wiki page for each version and linking it to the tag in the repo... But this seems like a great idea if I want my wiki riddled with hardcoded links.

Is there any other way to directly link a redmine version with a tag? Or a particular commit at least?

Comment: I'm personally curious if git tags can be used to create redmine versions if they don't already exist.

Comment: @xenoterracide I didn't have the time to work this out yet, but I'll have spare time after may and i'll be back on the backend project then... I'll post the solution here... I think it'll be based on [eykanal's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10113567/171711) using the Redmine API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine will create a page for each version, with a URL in the form of

```
http://<baseURL>/versions/##
```

where `##` is some internal pointer to the version. I would link to this, as (1) it contains all the important information about the version, and (2) it's unlikely to change in the future, barring a full server move (i.e., different base URI).

To address the comment regarding using git tags to create versions, I would approach this using [Git hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html). I can imagine a post-commit hook that examines a given commit to see whether it contains any new tags, and if so, it uses the [Redmine API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Versions) to create a new version.